# phpCas : How can you force renew authentication without going into a loop

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, phpcas

I got regular cas authentication to work using the forceAuthentication function, now I want to block single sign on with renew authentication but it keeps getting stuck in a loop.

Here is my code

```
require_once 'CAS/CAS.php';
phpCAS::setDebug();
phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, $cas_host, $cas_port, $cas_context, false);
phpCAS::setNoCasServerValidation();
phpCAS::renewAuthentication();
$user = phpCAS::getUser()
echo "welcome $user";
```

I'm using the latest version of phpcas : 1..33.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, $cas_host, $cas_port, $cas_context, false)
```

instead of this line:

```
phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, $cas_host, $cas_port, $cas_context);
```